# uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::SecureRandom in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new to Rails. I'm working with Devise and I'm getting this error when I try to sign in
uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::SecureRandom

I'm running Rails 3.2.8 and Devise 2.1.2

Let me know if you need to see anything else.

Full Trace

```
devise (1.1.rc0) lib/devise.rb:241:in `friendly_token'
devise (1.1.rc0) lib/devise/encryptors/base.rb:16:in `salt'
devise (1.1.rc0) lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:42:in `password='
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:85:in `block in  assign_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `each'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `initialize'
devise (1.1.rc0) lib/devise/controllers/internal_helpers.rb:68:in `new'
devise (1.1.rc0) lib/devise/controllers/internal_helpers.rb:68:in `build_resource'
devise (1.1.rc0) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `new'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in   `_run__3599699405390575833__process_action__3177745746729954596__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
devise (1.1.rc0) lib/devise/failure_app.rb:43:in `call'
devise (1.1.rc0) lib/devise/failure_app.rb:43:in `recall'
devise (1.1.rc0) lib/devise/failure_app.rb:27:in `respond'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
devise (1.1.rc0) lib/devise/failure_app.rb:16:in `call'
devise (1.1.rc0) lib/devise/failure_app.rb:16:in `call'
warden (0.10.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:114:in `call_failure_app'
warden (0.10.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:100:in `process_unauthenticated'
warden (0.10.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:47:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:339:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__656958163067492405__call__3074455685232703614__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/Malone/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/Malone/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/Malone/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: could you show backtrace please?

Comment: As I can see you are using `Devise 1.1` not `2.1.2`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

Try using `SecureRandom` instead of `ActiveSupport::SecureRandom`.  `ActiveSupport::SecureRandom` was deprecated in Rails 3.1 and removed in Rails 3.2

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.8. How do I change this out?

Comment: Replace all instances of `ActiveSupport::SecureRandom` with the string `SecureRandom`

Answer (score 1):

May be you are using

```
Devise.friendly_token
```

Instead of this use:

```
SecureRandom.base64(15).tr('+/=', 'xyz')
```

It may work.